# HTTP messages are not loaded correctly ( Android )

Tags: java, android, http, http-headers, android-volley

I would like to load json with [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) and download images using `BufferedInputStream`. Since these requests are made to LAN ip adresses on the non encrypted http port, I enabled `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

I get this error from Volley:

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 20 of {"data":{"foo":"bar"
```

I use `BufferedInputStream` like this:

```
private boolean getFileFromUrl(String url, String path) {
    try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream());
         FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
        byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

If I provide a `Content-Length` parameter on the server, sometimes I get this error:

```
W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:398)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:372)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:248)
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:347)
```

If I have no `Content-Length` parameter, some of the files are still not fully loaded. No `IOException` is thrown, but I get this error, if I try to read some of the images:

```
<Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment> from output_message
```

These errors happen randomly. If I open these urls with my browser, it can load them perfectly. I have no idea how to debug it.

I tried my `getFileFromUrl` with a `https` url, and then everíthing worked fine. Unfortunately I am not able to use https in this project, only http.

---

**Edit**

I created an executor service with one thread and then submit the `getFileFromUrl` calls in `Runnable` instances, but I still get the errors:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

Comment: If I try it on my phone, it works. This error occurs in the emulator only

Answer (score 2):

As it seems, that API (or OkHttp client) truncates the response body for some reason.

Either the OkHttp client has a low read-timeout (this value could be raised) or the API does not respond in time (or as whole JSON response). When it always responds properly in a web-browser, it should indeed be a(n Android) client-side issue. One way to handle this might be to catch that `ProtocolException`, delete the aborted download and then retry to download the file again.

But I'd assume that the `Content-Length` header's value might simply be wrong.
I mean, this value would be calculated correctly, when NOT setting it manually.
The client may only act abnormal upon erroneous instructions received.

`Content-Length` tells the client how large the receive-buffer has to be ...
and even if the response is not truncated, the client will reject the excess.

For example:

`Content-Length: 20` ...is what the API apparently reports.

```
{"data":{"foo":"bar"
```

`Content-Length: 22` ...is what the API should report.

```
{"data":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code you are just opening raw `http` connection with `OpenConnection`. However, I'm not sure it's right(and simple) way to load image. You can use any other library for Image loading, which would take care about **content length and headers**.

- For ex with `Glide`.

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {

                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    // do whatever you want with bitmap
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                }
            });
```

- To save just use your code above or.

```
public void write(String fileName, Bitmap bitmap) {
  try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
      bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap 
  instance
      // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: I get corrupted files, even if I use a library

Comment: @IterAtor Can you share raw response from the server in text format. And headers from the request response.

Comment: Huh? I can't see any image involved in the code provided. One could also setup an `Interceptor` in order to debug client-side, without having to use a desktop web-browser's `F12` tools. Retroftt2 & GSON are usually the default framework for handling whatever JSON API, not Glide. There's still nothing wrong with doing it all manually, because one should first understand how it works, before abstracting it all away.